# How can I make a 1K X 16 ROM chip with eight 256 X 8 ROM chips with an enable input and a decoder?

Tags: microchip, decoder, rom, chip-design

I came across this, which I'm guessing is correct, but I do not understand the shortcuts made here.  What are the 8's with slashes through them?  Do those represent 8 inputs and 8 outputs?  And can someone explain the bottom part - the D(7:0) and D(15:8)?  Assuming this is correct, that is.

[image: 1K X 16 ROM chip]

Comment: Yes, the number 8 next to a slash crossing a bus line indicates that it is an 8-bit bus, carrying either addresses or data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"What are the 8's with slashes through them?"*

It shows that the interconnect is a 8-bit wide bus.

> *"And can someone explain the bottom part - the D(7:0) and D(15:8)?"*

What the figure shows is 1K \$\times\$ 16 ROM. The data width is 16 bits. D(7:0) is the lower 8-bits of the 16-bit data line and D(15:8) is the higher 8-bit. So if you read the value at a particular address, the lower byte will be available at D(7:0) and higher byte at D(15:8).

> *"Assuming this is correct .."*

Yes the answer given in the figure looks perfect to me.

Comment: Okay.  There are 8 outputs for each ROM though, and it seems that four ROMs with 8 outputs each go to the lower 8-bits of the 16-bit data line.  How does that work?  It seems to me 32 outputs are converted to 8 outputs.  Forgive my ignorance.  I am learning.  And thank you.

Comment: "It seems to me 32 outputs are converted to 8 outputs." Exactly. At any given address, only one ROM is selected, so only that ROM's outputs are driving the bus. The other 3 ROMs are not selected, so their outputs don't affect the outputs.

Comment: Gotcha. Crystal clear.  Those shortcuts in drawing the circuit threw me off.  Thank you for taking the time to clarify things.